# Windows Server 2019 Get-Partition and 'IFS' partition type

Tags: powershell, storage, windows-server-2019

What is the 'IFS' partition type which sometimes reported by `Get-Partition`?  Specifically how is it related to MBR and GPT?  I haven't been able to find much documentation either through Google or microsoft.com.

As seen in the [Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-partition?view=win10-ps) and in my own output:

```
   DiskPath: \\?\scsi#disk&ven_vmware&prod_virtual_disk#5&1ec51bf7&0&000000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}

PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset                                                          Size Type
---------------  ----------- ------                                                          ---- ----
1                           1048576                                                       549 MB IFS
2                C           576716800                                                   99.46 GB IFS
```

Comment: according to wikipedia, it's the "installable file system". i am not sure just what that means in this case, tho. [*blush*]

Comment: I'm really interested in why this seems to differ across the different VMs I've spot checked.

Comment: unfortunately, i have no idea. [*blush*]

Answer (score 0):

It's equivalent to partition type code `7` (decimal / hexadecimal) in MBR/DOS partition table, which is used for NTFS and exFAT (and HPFS) in Windows. Apparently [Installable File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installable_File_System) was the very first type of filesystem that the code was designated for, and whoever wrote the PS cmdlet(s) decided to use the initial of that to represent the code.

In GUID partition table, there are no more partition type codes. Instead, the partition *type* GUID:

```
EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
```

has been chosen for any *[Microsoft basic data partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition)*, regardless of the filesystem on it.